De Rham Weil isomorphism commutes with M-V exact sequence?
For both De Rham cohomology of differential forms and Cohomology of $\mathbb{R}$ sheaf we have M-V sequence. I am curious that does the De Rham Weil isomorhpism commutes with these two long exact sequences?

How is the M-V-sequence for sheaf cohomology defined here?
